# Maui Android version Preprocessor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I have a migrated Xamarin.Forms solution, and using VS 2022.

The solution keeps the original structure of: Shared, Android and iOS projects.

In Android project I have the following code:

```
class DeviceInfoProvider: IDeviceInfoProvider
{
    public string GetAppVarsion()
    {
#if ANDROID33_0_OR_GREATER
        var packageManager = Platform.AppContext.PackageManager;
        var packageName = Platform.AppContext.PackageName;
        var flags = PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.Of((int)PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
        var appVer = packageManager.GetPackageInfo(packageName, flags).VersionName;
        return appVer;
#else
        var appVer = Platform.AppContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Platform.AppContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
        return appVer;
#endif
    }
}
```

For some reason VS 2022 does not respect the preprocessor,
and I see that the `#if ANDROID33_0_OR_GREATER` is used,
even though my connected mobile device is Api 31.0.

Is this a VS issue or do I need to configure something in the project to allow this to work?

Comment: The application can't know the device android version until it is installed. So you should use the runtime check for different android version instead of version preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessor directives are a **compile-time** feature, not a runtime feature.

Using a preprocessor with `ANDROID33_0_OR_GREATER` means that the target API is Android API 33.0 or greater, so if you have set the target API to 33.0, then the code within that if-clause will be included in the compiled IL code, otherwise it will not.

However, even devices running on Android API 31.0 can still *(attempt to)* execute the code, it just might throw runtime exceptions, because some APIs might not be available on that specific OS version.

Instead of using a preprocessor directive, you should use a runtime check for the API version of the OS you're running the app on, e.g.:

```cs
if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33))
{
    // do stuff that is only supported on API 33 or higher here
}
```

Since you seem to be checking the app version, you may also want to give the [App information](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-information) a try, MAUI already exposes properties for this:

```cs
string version = AppInfo.Current.VersionString;
```

Comment: I was moving away from an existing runtime check, thinking it makes more sense to have it in compile time.
I was strictly speaking about the IDE itself not recognizing that I was going to debug using an API 31.0 phone.

Comment: The IDE still interprets the preprocessor as a compile-time feature and doesn't check it against the runtime. The IDE, especially Visual Studio 2022, highlights the code based on the selected target framework you're building against.

Comment: That's the thing.
We still have the 3 projects structure.
Meaning, Android project is set as startup project.
Second, the device I'm going to debug on should dictate to the IDE/compiler which API will be used, no?

Comment: "the device I'm going to debug on should dictate to the IDE/compiler which API will be used, no?" - **No**, that's not how it works. Device => runtime, compiler => compile time, IDE => static code analysis. etc.